# EM algorithm early stopping

Tags: probability, inference, expectation-maximization

Assume there are a set of latent variables $X$, a set of observed variables $Y$ and some parameters $\Theta$. I am using EM algorithm to compute $X$ and $\theta$. In the E step, it computes $p(X|Y,\Theta^t)$. In the M step it computes $\Theta^{t+1} = \arg\max Q(\Theta|\Theta^t)$ where $Q$ is the auxiliary function. Assume again that for any parameter $\theta$, there is no closed form to compute $\theta^{t+1}$, gradient ascent method has to be used to update $\theta^{t+1}$.

The ground truth of $X$ is available for evaluation. My problem is: in the M step of each iteration, it uses gradient ascent method to update $\theta^{t+1}$ iteratively, if I stop the gradient ascent process earlier, i.e., before $Q$ reaches maximum, and then use the current $\hat{\Theta}$ to infer $X$: $\hat{X} = p(X|Y,\hat{\Theta})$, the accuracy is better than the case where $X$ is inferred by the optimal $\Theta^*$, i.e., $\Theta^* = \arg\max Q(\Theta|\Theta^t)$. Anyone could please explain the reason?

**Update 1**: Context of the problem

There $n$ objects $\{o_1,o_2,\dots,o_n\}$ and $m$ sensors $\{s_1,s_2\dots,s_m\}$. Each object can take one of the two states 1 and 0. The object states can be observed by a subset of the sensors. The observation of object $o_j$ by a source $s_i$ is $y_{ij}$. The true state $x_j$ of object $o_j$ is unknown and treated as a latent variable. The sensors have different accuracies, the accuracy of $s_i$ is $\theta_j$ and is treated as a model parameter. Given the truth state $x_j$ of object $o_j$ and the accuracy $\theta_i$ of sensor $s_i$, the probability of $s_i$ observes the true state is $p(y_{ij} = k | x_j = k, \theta_i) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-\theta_i)} = \sigma(\theta_i)$ where $\sigma$ is the logistic function, and $p(y_{ij} = k' | x_j = k, \theta_i) = 1-\sigma(\theta_i)$.

The E-step is given as: $p(x_j|Y,\Theta) \propto p(x_j) \prod\limits_i p(y_{ij}|x_j,\theta_i)$ where $p(x_j)$ is the prior of $x_j$.

The M-step is to maximize:

$Q = \sum_{ij}p^1[y_{ij} \ln\sigma(\theta_i) + (1-y_{ij}) \ln(1-\sigma(\theta_i))] + \sum_{ij}p^0[y_{ij} \ln\sigma(\theta_i) + (1-y_{ij}) \ln(1-\sigma(\theta_i))]$

where $p^k = p(x_j=k|Y,\Theta)$.

$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial \theta_i} = \sum_j (p^1 y_{ij} + p^0(1-y_{ij} )-\sigma(\theta_i))$

To maximize $Q$, it needs to iteratively update $\theta_i$: ${\theta_i}^{new} = {\theta_i}^{old} - \lambda \frac{\partial Q}{\partial \theta_i}$.

Back to the question, in a M step, use $\Theta^*$ to denote the stationary point that maximize $Q$, and $\hat{\Theta}$ is a point computed by the above $\theta_i$ update formula before $Q$ reaches maxima. I find using $\hat{\Theta}$ to infer $X$ is better than using $\Theta^*$.

Comment: Could you describe the specifics of the problem a little more, for example, what the likelihood function is, what the latent variables are, etc.?  This is likely to be a problem-specific or domain-specific effect, so knowing more about the domain would help.

Comment: context is updated.

Comment: How are you defining accuracy?

Comment: Accuracy is 1- error rate. Since the ground truth is available, we can use the inferred true states $X$ to compare with the ground truths.

Comment: What you have are estimated probabilities, not inferred true states.  If you are basing your evaluation on the latter, $p(x) = 0.999$ and $p(x) = 0.501$ are equivalent estimates (assuming you infer the true state by picking the state with  highest probability.)  If you are basing your evaluation on the former, they aren't.      Extending this, compare $p(x_1=1) = 0.999, p(x_2=1)=0.499$ and $p(x_1=1)=0.501, p(x_2=1) = 0.501$ when $x_1=x_2=1$: the former is worse with the accuracy metric, but (almost certainly much) better with the criterion used by the EM algorithm.

Comment: Given that the evaluation metric is not monotonically related to the likelihood, there's no reason to assume the estimates that maximize one will also maximize the other.